# How would I go about creating an array in Objective-C in which every item has multiple properties?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, multidimensional-array

For example, an array that contains several "item" elements that each contain "price", "location", and "condition" values. Would this be considered a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: You can have an array of NSDictionary objects. OR you can create a custom class with those properties, and have your array store those objects.

Answer (score 3):

You either need an array of `NSDictionary` objects or an array of instances of your own model class, probably called `Item`.

**Item.h**

```
@interface Item : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) float price;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
// etc...
@end
```

**Item.m**

```
@implementation Item
@end
```

**Usage:**

```
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Item *item;
item = [[Item alloc] init];
item.price = 25.99;
item.name = @"Bluray movie";
[items addObject:item];

// add other objects...
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like each "item" element in your array should either be an instance of a custom model object with "price", "location", and "condition" properties or an NSDictionary with keys matching these properties.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that :)
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"100$",@"USA",@"good"] forKeys:@[@"price",@"location",@"condition"];

This is how you make a muti dimensional array which will contain a key value pairs of your entites.

This is how you use NSDictionary

Comment: NSDictionary* dict = @{@"price": @"100$", @"location": @"USA", @"condition": @"good"};

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the specific requirements of your application, you could make an array of NSArrays which contained the item at one common index, the price at another, and so on. Or you could also use an array of NSDictionaries, or an array of objects with those properties. Only the first is a "multidimensional array."